# How to insert into database with input type=month?

Tags: php, date, input, credit-card

billing.php

```
Expiry Date: <input type="month" id="ccexpirydate" name="ccexpirydate" value="<?php echo $row['expirydate'] ?>"/>
```

Firstly, how do I retrieve from database only showing month and year?

dobilling.php

```
$expiryDate = $_POST['ccexpirydate'];

$query = "INSERT INTO bill (ccexpirydate) VALUES ('" . $expiryDate . "')";
```

Secondly, after editing the expiry date and submitting the form, how to do I update the database with input type=month? Showing only month and year. As currently, my database would show 0000-00-00.

Comment: "_my database would show 0000-00-00_" That means that the column field `ccexpirydate` is of DATE type. It expects that the input variable is of DATE type, not only month. Also you didn't mention which SQL db you are using.

Comment: try changing the column field type of ccexpirydate to varchar(8) if you want to store mm-yyyy format into DB

Answer (score 1):

Date inputs are passed in the standard format. Regardless of what is shown to the user (which will be their local format), your server will receive `YYYY-MM`.

You can either save this as a `CHAR(7)` column, or add `"-01"` to the end of it and keep your current `DATE` column.

Comment: Or add the last day of the month rather than 01 to produce a valid format and the true expiry date and allow for a simple `>` query to detect it later on

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate any random date to the variable while inserting into table, like

```
$expiryDate = $_POST['ccexpirydate'];
$expiryDate = $expiryDate."28"; //any date
```

And while retrieving and displaying in form, you can use it like:

```
<input type="month" value="<?php echo date('Y-m', strtotime($table_name['date_field'])); ?>"> //Y-m will give you date like, eg. 2017-11. Input type month will automatically read it as.. November 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the column as CHAR(7) and it will work